# Flask - Pass Variables From Redirect to render_template

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I have a question regarding redirecting to a function that renders a template.  I have two functions:

```
@user.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('register.html')
    email = request.form['email']
    if User.query.filter(User.email == email).first() is not None:
        flash('Account already exists for this email address!')
        return redirect(url_for('user.login'))
```

and

```
@user.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    return "Hello"
```

In the first function, with the line `return redirect(url_for('user.login'))`, I want to pass the email variable with that redirect, so I can have `render_template` in the second function display that variable on an HTML page.  I tried the following:

```
return redirect(url_for('user.login', defaultEmail=email))
```

in the first function and

```
return render_template('login.html', defaultEmail=email))
```

but it gives me `NameError: global name 'email' is not defined`.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `url_for` should pass `email` through the query string. It can by accessed by `login` as part of `request.args`.

```
email = request.args.get('defaultEmail')
```

Comment: Great, thank so much! In my jinja template, I checked `{% if defaultEmail %}` to see if that variable existed before loading it into my template.